# how to resolve issue where Vagrant fails to bring up VirtualBox on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am getting the following issue trying to start a VM using vagrant & VirtualBox on my MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) running OS X 10.11.6.  I have tried VirtualBox version 5.0.26, 5.1.0 and 5.1.2.  I have searched around and tried all the suggestions I could find. what do I need to do to fix this issue?

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "23e70124-39c9-46ea-a45d-cf34c0e8a251", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
```

Comment: can you launch the VM from virtual box directly ? does it work ok

Comment: no, I cannot launch the VM from VirtualBox directly

Comment: Whats is the error message you get

Comment: Vagrant is simply passing through the error from VirtualBox: 

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg.

The VM session was aborted.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with setting the networking to NAT mode (which is done by vagrant). To bring up the vm, go into virtualbox, edit the vm network settings to something like bridged and start the vm and it should work.

However, the downside is that the vagrant up command does not work (down works once the vm has been started manually).

At this point, I am also struggling to find a solution (may be something to do with El Capitan)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, though I am on os x 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Downgrading to VirtualBox 4.3.40 worked for me.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3

Comment: unfortunately that seems to cause another problem: 

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.